# Android Fit API Basic Sensors Sample Fails to Build

Tags: android

I'm unable to build the Android Fit basic sensors sample due to a missing dependency. I'm new to gradle so I don't know how to fix the build issue.  How do I add this missing dependency?

Pre-requisites says:

> Android API Level >v9
>
> Android Build Tools >v19
>
> Android Support Repository

My environment:

> Android SDK Build-tools: 23.0.5
>
> Android 5.0 (API 21)
>
> Android Support Repository 7
>
> Android Support Library 21
>
> Google Play services 21

Build:

> $ gradlew build
>
> Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has
>   been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
>   ':app:_debugCompile'.
>
> Could not find any version that matches
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+.
>
> Required by: BasicSensorsApi:app:unspecified Try: Run with
>   --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.582 secs

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Google Repository as well:

[image: Google Repository]

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html